# Dynamically created TextView in FrameLayout has no width

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, width

I'm trying to add a TextView in code to a framelayout.  This sits above an imageview in the z order of the framelayout.  The ultimate aim is to allow the creation of a screenshot from the framelayout that shows the image and the text that has been overlayed on to it.  I have this working when using a textview created in xml but not in the dynamic code version.  The create bitmap method returns an error complaining about the width of the textbox being 0.  In the code below I am trying to capture just the textview as an image to identify what the issue is, as the captured image from the framelayout did not contain the contents of the textview as expected.  In doing this I was able to find the width error and I believe it is this that is the root of the problem.  I have tried to set the textview's width using setWidth and also using the LayoutParams.  The end result is always that the textview has no width although it can be seen on the handset clearly.  I think I am missing something between the dynamic creation and the existing xml which results in the 0 width.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction please?

The code is as follows

```
   public void applyTextToImage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button

    //Hide the virtual keyboard


    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    //Get the text to overlay on the image
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();

    //Bring the overlay layout to the front
   //LinearLayout overlay_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_Overlay_Layout);
   //overlay_layout.bringToFront();

    //Apply the new text to the text box

    /* Old code to get the view that is shown in the layout
    TextView text_overlay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image_Overlay);
    text_overlay.bringToFront();
    text_overlay.setText(message);
    */

    //New code to create a view dynamically instead

    TextView text_Overlay = new TextView(this);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        text_Overlay.setId(Utils.generateViewId());
    }
    else
    {
        text_Overlay.setId(TextView.generateViewId()); //static class
    }
    FrameLayout image_Layout =  (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_Layout);
    //View image_Layout =  (View) findViewById(R.id.image_Layout);
    //FrameLayout.LayoutParams fParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams fParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    fParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

   // text_Overlay.setMaxWidth(image_Layout.getWidth());
   // text_Overlay.setWidth(image_Layout.getWidth());
    //image_Layout.addView(text_Overlay, fParams);
    image_Layout.addView(text_Overlay, fParams);
    Toast.makeText(this,"TextView Width: " + text_Overlay.getWidth(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //TODO: Something has forced the dynamic layout to not be saved in  the bitmap try removing the params and set the values on the textview itself
    //TODO: for some reason the width keeps coming back as 0 could be that the image_Layout is 0 too

    text_Overlay.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    text_Overlay.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    //text_Overlay.setWidth(250dp);

    text_Overlay.setTextSize(pixels);
    text_Overlay.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    text_Overlay.bringToFront();
    text_Overlay.setText(message);
    text_Overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //End of new dynamic code

    if (folderCheck()){
        try {
            String filePath = getFilePath();
            int myId = text_Overlay.getId();

            Bitmap bitmap;
            View v1 = findViewById(myId);

            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            v1.buildDrawingCache();

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            // End imported code

            streamBitmapToFile(bitmap, filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.e("Bitmap Creation","Couldn't create bitmap error as: "  + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

XML contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false">
    <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my"-->

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:enabled="false"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="applyTextToImage"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:id="@+id/overlayButton"/>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />

   <!--<TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_Overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"/>-->

</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/open_gallery"
    android:onClick="openGallery">
</Button>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/new_image"
    android:onClick="newImage">
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view has not been measured yet. Until the system does another layout pass, the view reports its width as zero.

In my opinion, you are better off leaving the TextView in the XML layout and simply making it invisible (`android:visibility="invisible"`) until you need it, then make it visible prorammatically with `setVisbility(View.VISIBLE)`. (Note that if you set it to be `gone`, it will also not be measured.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying!  I need to be able to add more than one of these (and an unknown number) which is why I need to do it via code.  Is there a way to force the system to do another layout pass in code?

Comment: @PaleNeanderthal You can only request that a layout pass be performed, but it will not be performed immediately (meaning you can't make the request and then use `getWidth()` on the next line). Also, for the same reason that you cannot use `getWidth()` right away, getting the drawing cache for the view will not work because the view hasn't been drawn yet.

Comment: @PaleNeanderthal Depending on what your needs are, you might look at the `ViewTreeObserver` class and see if any of the callback interfaces would be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks Karakuri. This was exactly what I needed, implementing the ViewTreeObserver OnGlobalLayout Listener allowed me to call the image creation code after the layout had been redrawn and so the system reported the correct sizes for everything and in turn allowed the bitmap creation to happen.

Answer (score 0):

For reference Karakuri pointed out the weaknesses and the path to follow to resolve them.

Extra code that was implemented for the listener is as follows.

```
IMAGE_CAPTURE_REQUESTED = true;

    // New Listener
    ViewTreeObserver vto = image_Layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                image_Layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            else
            {
                image_Layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }

            if (IMAGE_CAPTURE_REQUESTED) {
                //int myId = text_Overlay.getId();
                //Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Text Overlay Width " + text_Overlay.getWidth() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                overlayTextAndExportImage();
            }
        }
    }); //End New Listener
```

The new overlayTextAndImportImage calls all the image creation routines after the layout has been redrawn.